# Set a unique design or color for the top 3 rows in a generated table in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a table that is pretty similar to the one provided in material angular website as an example. The only difference is the table I'm making is constantly changing so I cannot use this method:

`[ngClass]="{'top-rank-color': row.id== '1'}"`

Is there a way to color the top 3 row on the table regardless of its content?

This is the table I am referring to:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/yjpllxbylapx?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

Comment: `tr:nth-child(...) { background-color: ... }`

Comment: Thank you for this, how do I specifically add this to only `<tbody>` ? So it doesn't color the child of the header.

Comment: Make the selector more specific. You might want to read about CSS and how it works if you're doing web stuff ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this in your `table-basic-example.css`

```css
.mat-row:nth-child(-n+3) {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

or

```css
::ng-deep .mat-table tbody tr:nth-child(-n+3) {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

or

```css
::ng-deep .mat-table tbody .mat-row:nth-child(-n+3) {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your linked stackblitz example, you can open `table-basic-example.css` and add the following `CSS` rule to color the first 3 rows:

```css
.mat-row:nth-child(1),
.mat-row:nth-child(2),
.mat-row:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```